# Recessed lighting on edge of concrete slab

Tags: concrete

I am thinking of adding recessed stair riser lights (such as [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08RBQJ61H)) into the edge of a concrete slab I will be pouring. The lights are low-voltage landscape type lights that fit in a standard 1-gang electrical box.

I don't anticipate any problem attaching the boxes and conduit to the form before concrete is poured. I am concerned, however,  that with a 4" slab, a 2.8" wide electrical box centered on the slab height leaves only 0.6" of concrete above the box. The edge of the slab is an area where foot traffic is likely.

Is 0.6" of concrete on top of a recessed electrical box sufficient? Do I need to make the slab thicker? Are there other solutions, such as adding some kind of reinforcement over the electrical box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least 1.5" of cover for concrete that will be exposed to weather.  0.6" will just spall off.